# Magento 2: Di Compile SER Files

Tags: magento2, compiler, setup-di-compile, magento-2.1.4

When we run

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

It will generate below files in `\magento\var\di` folder

```
adminhtml.ser
crontab.ser
frontend.ser
global.ser
setup.ser
webapi_rest.ser
webapi_soap.ser
```

I opened one of the files & it stores all serialize data.

What is meaning of `.SER` files. What actually it stores? Above mentioned files only we have or others as well?

As per my knowledge it compiles XML files within Theme & Modules & Check dependancy between them

Answer (score 1):

.SER is a common extension for serialized objects.

as far as the files in the **\magento\var\di** folder are concerned:
They are generated once you have executed setup:di:compile command.

So, we all have that.

**It stores the classes and its dependencies, i.e. the arguments passed in the __construct() of that particular class. This will be used to check dependencies between classes.**